# Any function to perform on rdd as a whole

Tags: apache-spark

I am new on spark. I need a function that will do a work on an RDD as a whole. Not on each element on RDD that map() do.
Example:
`JavaRDD<String> str= sc.parallelize(list);
 str.map(func);`
now I want to perfrom func on str as whole not on each element of str. 
Is there anything that serves my purpose.

Comment: Could you give an example, of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to achieve but I just want to say that you can apply two type of operation on an `RDD`, here's a simple explanation from the [official guidline](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)

> transformations, which create a new dataset from an existing one, and actions, which return a value to the driver program after running a computation on the dataset. For example, map is a transformation that passes each dataset element through a function and returns a new RDD representing the results. On the other hand, reduce is an action that aggregates all the elements of the RDD using some function and returns the final result to the driver program

I think you have to use the `action` type of operations such as `reduce` or `count`...ext

Hope this help you, otherwise please edit the question and explain exactly what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you are trying to achieve but you could use mapPartition that operates over a whole partition of data

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest lets transform it to a DataFrame!

```
from pyspark.sql import toDF
df = rdd.toDF(['column', 'value'])
```

It solves your problem i think, or please tell me why you do not want to use the DataFrame object